# Extream usage of RAM memory by ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, bytearrayoutputstream

So my problem sounds like this. I need to make a base64 encoded string of a file and for this, I use this method:

```
public String getStringFile(File f) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String encodedFile= "", lastVal;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
        int bytesRead;

        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        output64.close();
        encodedFile =  output.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lastVal = encodedFile;

    return lastVal;
}
```

and the thing is when I try to encode file something around 20 Mb (exact file size is 19,35 Mb) I get an OutOfMemoryException.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is the problem: encodedFile =  output.toString();

Comment: I know the problem is in whole ByteArrayOutputStream but i just dont know what to use else =(

Comment: CommonsWare explained it. Id say write the encoded String to a file, then use it from the storage instead from the memmory

Comment: `i just dont know what to use else`. Please tell how you upload the base64 string now.

Comment: I build up the string and then put it in POJO from what I build body of the request that I send to server.

Comment: Wrong as even if you can create a big base64 string then POJO will claim again as much memory. Use HttpUrlConnection and upload the file yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

If you upload the base64 yourself with HttpUrlConnection you can do way with the ByteArrayOutputStream and replace above lines -while directly uploading- with

```
OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream();
Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Untested.

You could also directly base64 encode to a `FileOutputStream` of course.

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(......);
Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and then upload that file with POJO.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong

You are attempting to encode a ~20MB file using base64 into a string. You will not have adequate heap space on many Android devices to have a single memory allocation that large.

> how can I fix this issue?

If "this issue" is "create a ~26MB string of base64-encoded data", there is no reliable way to do this. You would have to find some other solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve by creating such a string.

Comment: thing is that I need to upload a file to a remote server and it accepts a file as a base64 string only  so I have no choice actually.

Comment: @VladZbuker: The server may accept the data as base64, but the server does not care at all whether this is a single string in Android or not.

Comment: I got the point but I don't quite understand how to split string or something like that :(

Comment: @VladZbuker: greenapps' answer covers a couple of options for that. The details depend a lot on what HTTP API you are using (OkHttp, `HttpUrlConnection`, etc.).

Comment: I'm using retrofit2 for all REST in app so that leaves  me with OkHttp.

Comment: @VladZbuker: Retrofit builds on top of Okio. Look for an option that allows you to stream in this portion of the REST request, rather than loading the whole thing in memory at once. This may require greenapps' intermediate-file approach.

Comment: yeah, I got it, thanks for the response and have a good day :)